# How to get all members in a Guild using discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I need to get all the members in a discord server/guild. And this solution has to work on discord servers with max amount of people in it.

I have tried the following

```
async function getMembers(message){
    console.log('getting members')
    let members = await message.guild.members.fetch();
    console.log('members are \n'+members);
}
```

and

```
message.guild.members.cache.array().forEach(member => {})
```

But the first code block wouldn't ever get the promise, and if I try it without the await it will say that it is pending in the form of {}. While the second solution wouldn't get everyone in the server, only those in the cache I am pretty sure. I.e. in my test server with 6 people it would only get 2 of those people.

**EDIT** After a long time the first block would throw an error saying that *"Members didn't arrive in time."* So I am assuming it is timing out.

I am honestly just so confused and just want to know all the members in a guild ;-;

Comment: It is very much not recommended to fetch all members inside of a guild, as just the process of fetching one person takes a while, and fetching tens, hundreds or even thousands of those people is just a real overdose on the bot. Nowadays, most Discord users are already cached, therefore I'd highly recommend to work with `message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username))` (just putting `member` would spam your console with hundreds of objects and their properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of spent time looking for an answer I finally stumbled on this article

https://www.publish0x.com/bala/how-i-fixed-an-issue-with-discord-bot-not-caching-all-users-xjjndxy

For me, I could not have it another way and HAD to fetch all users.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, it's not recommended to fetch massive amount of members in a guild unless you need them, it's not particularly related to performance, how fast it can fetch depends on how stable the connection of your host machine is. If you have a fast connection, fetching all members could take no time at all.

Most members will be cached, and so you could just use the solution above:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username));
//credit to @Bqre
```

Your code above might be timing out because of the amount of guildMember objects being logged to the console, make sure you are logging `member.username` not the object itself.

Comment: Yeah, I later realized for what I need to do, I don't actually need everyone in the guild to work and I used the cache. Thanks!